# How do i construct an instance of the OneDimensionalArrays class using an object instance

Tags: java, arrays

To begin, I am a very beginner to Java. In this moderately simple program I need to construct an instance of the `OneDimensionalArrays`class using the object instance, call `createIntegers`to create an array of integers. 
I can not figure out how from my main to allow the user to enter in the size of an array they wish to create and have my `OneDimensionalArray`and `printArray`methods to create the array and size that the user wants.

```
    package one_dimensional_array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneDimensionalArrays {

   static int[] createIntegers(int size_of_array)
    {
        int myArray[];
        myArray = new int [10];
        myArray[0] = 0;
        myArray[1] = 100;
        myArray[2] = 200;
        myArray[3] = 300;
        myArray[4] = 400;
        myArray[5] = 500;
        myArray[6] = 600;
        myArray[7] = 700;
        myArray[8] = 800;
        myArray[9] = 900;

        return myArray;

    }
    void printArray(int[] myArray)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter size of array to create: ");
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user to define the size of the array by doing this:

```
static int[] createIntegers(int size_of_array)
{
    int[] myArray= new int [size_of_array];
    
        //You can use this to allow the user to set each element with the value 
        //that they want
        for(int ii = 0; ii < myArray.length; ii++){
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter array value for element " + ii + ": ");
           int num = keyboard.nextInt();
           myArray[ii] = num;
        
        }

    return myArray;

}
static void printArray(int[] myArray)
{
   //Check to make sure the array has values to prevent errors
   if((myArray.length != 0) && (myArray != null)){
         for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Array Value: " + myArray[i]);
            }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of array to create: ");
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Call the static method, returning the results
    int[] myArray = OneDimensionalArrays.createIntegers(num); 

    //Close scanner
    keyboard.close(); 

    //Pass results into static method to be printed out
    OneDimensionalArrays.printArray(myArray);
}
```

This will print out the results of your array as well. Here is a sample output:

> Enter size of array to create: 5
>
> Enter array value for element 0: 1
>
> Enter array value for element 1: 2
>
> Enter array value for element 2: 3
>
> Enter array value for element 3: 4
>
> Enter array value for element 4: 5
>
> Array Value: 1
>
> Array Value: 2
>
> Array Value: 3
>
> Array Value: 4
>
> Array Value: 5

As a note, using static methods aren't using the object instance. A static method is a method that can be used without creating an object.

Comment: Awesome that is definetely printing out the array for me, but i have two questions.. first, do you have any idea why when i am debugging my program, right away from starting at Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); gives me a source not found error? When i run the program normal it simply prints out my entire array regardless of what size the user enters. How can i get the program to only print the first two arrays when the user enters 2?

Comment: if you can please try to explain as much as possible that would be great. I need to learn this information not simply have you do my homework for me..

Comment: You are printing out the entire array because your print method is iterating over the entire array. If you want to print a certain amount of elements, you need to pass the number of elements you want to print into the print method, and iterate that many times.

Comment: So i would need to take the number the user gives me, have my createIntegers determine which arrays will be used, then have my printArray evaluate the number of arrays i want to print and print them? 

sorry, again I am a very very beginner java programmer. I am trying to wrap my head around how everything works with it.

I really appreciate your help and patience with me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Arrays". You only have 1 array. Arrays would mean you have more than 1 array. Currently, your `createIntegers` method is creating 1 array with 10 element. So if you want the user to print 2 of those elements, you would take the value the user inputs, and pass that to the print method.

Comment: ok, so printArray needs to evaluate 'num' (number of elements to print), and grab those two elements from my createInteger array and print those two out? So say the user enters 2, this is how i would set this up if say, when they enter 2, i want array[0] = 0; and array[1] = 100; to print?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you pass in the array (like you do now), and the number of elements you want print you. So the method signature would look like: `printArray(int[] myArray, int numToPrint)`